# Sitecore 8 experience editor and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, sitecore, sitecore8

Following javascript is not working in page editor mode:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"script","<script src=\"//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js\"></script><script src=\"http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js\"></script>");
```

I changed it to:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"script","<script src=\"//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js\"></script><script src=\"http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js\"></script><script>scSitecore&&scSitecore.prototype.initializeModalDialogs()</script>");
```

But now nothing is getting saved in page editor mode.

To include jquery in noConflict mode, I have added following line of codes:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", "<script src=\"//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js\"></script><script src=\"http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js\"></script><script>jQuery.noConflict();window.onload = function(){var mainDiv = $( \"main\" );}</script>");
```

To include highchart I have added a div with id as "containers" and following line in code behind. In normal view highchart is getting displayed but not in page editor mode.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "charts", "<script src=\"containers.js\"></script>");
```

Code of Containers.js:

```
$(function () {
$('#containers').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '°C'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }, {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
    }, {
        name: 'Berlin',
        data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
    }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
    }]
});

});
```

Answer (score 2):

> To avoid editing issues in Experience Editor use jQuery JavaScript
>   library in the No-Conflict mode.
>
> Please check the following article for details:
>   http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

It's all in the Sitecore documentation on kb.sitecore.net ( see https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/286042 ).

---

**EDIT**

Try to Wrap you `container.js` code in :

```
(function ($) {
    ...
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I have added the changes mentioned in link. But then highchart is not getting displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I have added following line of codes:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", "<script src=\"//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js\"></script><script src=\"http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js\"></script><script>jQuery.noConflict();window.onload = function(){var mainDiv = $( \"main\" );}</script>");
```

To include highchart I have added a div with id as "containers" and following line in code behind. In normal view highchart is getting displayed but not in page editor mode.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "charts", "<script src=\"containers.js\"></script>");
```

Comment: This should be an edit of your original question, not a new answer. What is the code in `containers.js`?

Comment: See edited answer. And you may want to delete your answer - it's not an answer, it's edit to your question ;)