# Why jQuery functions are not loading in Preview Mode?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore8

jQuery functions are not loading  In Sitecore preview mode,but in Experience Editor it is working fine, how can I fix this issue? I have attached a image also.
[image]

Comment: jQuery breaks your preview.

Comment: Use js.noConflict(); , after loading new jquery min js

Comment: I would prefer the errors as text instead of images...

Comment: Make sure that your js libraries are loading in preview mode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614617/sitecore-8-experience-editor-and-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You need to run jQuery in no-conflict mode. See this kb article for details: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/286042

To run jQuery in no-conflict mode you can either wrap your script like this:

```
(function ($) {
    ...
})(jQuery);
```

or setup your jquery like this:

```
<!-- Putting jQuery into no-conflict mode. -->
<script src="prototype.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
// $j is now an alias to the jQuery function; creating the new alias is optional.

$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j( "div" ).hide();
});

// The $ variable now has the prototype meaning, which is a shortcut for
// document.getElementById(). mainDiv below is a DOM element, not a jQuery object.
window.onload = function() {
    var mainDiv = $( "main" );
}

</script>
```

credit: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

This post also answers a similar question: [Sitecore 8 experience editor and jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614617/sitecore-8-experience-editor-and-jquery)

Comment: Not sure what version OP is using, but, FWIW, 8.1 [fixes this](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/Sitecore%2081/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2081%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes) issue ( _The $ variable was initialized by the Experience Editor - jQuery compatibility issue. This has been fixed._ )